# SSH connection tunneling refused

Tags: networking, ssh, netcat, ssh-tunnel

I have a virtual machine located inside a private network. 
So firstly, I should come in `server.com` and then come in `my-machine`.

I want to make `ssh-tunnel` from my laptop to `my-machine`.

```
ssh -v -A -nNT -L 40000:127.0.0.1:40000 login@server.com ssh -v -nNT -L 40000:127.0.0.1:40000 my-machine &
```

Now I want to test `ssh-tunnel` with `netcat`.

I run at `my-machine`:

```
nc -l 40000
```

At my laptop:

```
~ ❯❯❯ nc 127.0.0.1 40000
```

But it gives me:

```
debug1: Connection to port 40000 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 40000 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 40000 for 127.0.0.1 port 40000, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 49692 to 127.0.0.1 port 40000, nchannels 3
```

Why this happen and how to fix it? I expected that anything I type in my laptop console will  appear in `my-machine` console.

What last string means? Especially `127.0.0.1 port 49692` why this port is used? I never type it.

```
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 40000 for 127.0.0.1 port 40000, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 49692 to 127.0.0.1 port 40000, nchannels 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Every TCP connection is point to point needs two pairs of IP addresses and ports. Reading all the message (not just the part you showed):

```
connect from 127.0.0.1 port 49692
```

So indeed you are connecting to the port 40000, but you are connecting **from** port 49692 (randomly assigned for your `netcat` or some of the forwarded steps).

> How to fix this problem?

This double-jump forwarding does not work, because you need the second established before the first one.

Also you are using `-N` switch for the first command, which is preventing running the second `ssh` command.

But I would give it a shot with ProxyCommand, which will make you connect to the destination with single command directly from your host:

```
ssh -v -nNT -L 40000:127.0.0.1:40000 \
    -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p login@server.com" my-machine &
```

Comment: How to fix this problem?

Comment: Added more details in the answer.

Comment: Why I need the second connection established before the first one?

Comment: Because you need to forward the remote protocol to local and once you establish the first connection, on the jumphost, there is no port to forward (yet).

Comment: About `shot with ProxyCommand`: is it correct? I have an error that `Connection closed by remote host`. It is worth to note that `my-machine` is not directly visible to me.

Comment: It should work, though I didn't test it. Have a look into the manual page. Run it with debug options `-vvv` (both `ssh` commands)`, post the logs. Test again.